# how to write Elasticsearch(NEST for .net) query to produce result like power set?

Tags: elasticsearch, asp.net-core-webapi, kibana, nest, powerset

I'm using Elasticsearch with default implementation for searching products of my eCommerce site. This default implementation is producing considerably relevant search results. However, I want my search results to be in a specific format exactly like a [power set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set).

For example, if I search with ***milk powder***, the results should have a priority like

1. milk powder ( e.g. full cream ***milk powder***)
2. powder milk ( e.g. instant ***powder milk*** formula)
3. milk (e.g. liquid cow ***milk***)
4. powder (e.g. insect ***powder***)

My current implemented code is:

```
            results = _client.Search<ProductDefault>(s => s
                .Query(q => q
                    .Match(t => t
                        .Field(f => f.title_en.ToLower())
                        .Query(parm.k.ToLower())
                    )
                ).Size(1000)
            );
```

how to refactor the above query to produce search results exactly like a power set?